# Laravel: How to set multiple cookie with one response?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I used to the to send response with a cookie by this way:

```
return $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('region', $region));
```

It works perfectly. But now I want to send a response with multiple cookies set, could anyone please give me some suggestion about that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
return $response
    ->withCookie(cookie()->forever('region', $region))
    ->withCookie(cookie()->forever('somethingElse', $somethingElse));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use Cookie queues to queue them, so that they will be automatically attached to the response when it is ready.

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('region', $region));
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forever('region2', $region2));
```